# How do I tag a project with Subversive programmatically?

Tags: eclipse, svn, subversive

I'd like to tag a project I have checked out from SVN as part of what a Wizard provided by my plugin does.

I assume that `org.eclipse.team.svn.core.operation.remote.PreparedBranchTagOperation` might be what I'm looking for, but I couldn't find an API explaining the use. Has anyone done that before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PreparedBranchTagOperation was the right guess, but as a look at `org.eclipse.team.svn.ui.action.local.BranchTagAction.getBranchTagOperation` revealed, I needed to put it in a `CompositeOperation` with matching `FreezeExternalsOperation` and `RestoreExternalsOperation`.